# Heroku app.json configuration not working for review app

Tags: heroku

Below is my app.json:

```json
{
    "environments": {
      "review": {
        "addons": [
            "heroku-postgresql:in-dyno"
        ],
        "scripts": {
            "postdeploy": "php artisan migrate --seed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

In my understanding, a review app with such configuration should be starting with Postgres DB and run my script afterwards; the app starts, yet no Postgres is attached and I don't see any errors in Build log nor Application Logs.

How should my app.json be structured to do what I want?

Comment: Does the app **work**? Your question is a bit unclear on that front. If it doesn't, it's possible that `php artisan migrate --seed` needs a `--force` parameter to bypass the "your app is in production, continue y/n?" prompt.

Comment: The app does work. Added clarification on that part

Comment: OK, so your `app.json` is doing what you told it to do, and your app works. What's the issue?

Comment: `yet no Postgres is attached`, `In my understanding, a review app with such configuration should be starting with Postgres DB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in-dyno` means a Postgres instance **won't** be attached - it'll be directly within the dyno itself. Not seeing errors in the build log would, thus, be normal.

Comment: Ah, silly me - I've copied this from other configuration and was surprised it's not working, but reading it over at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci-in-dyno-databases I shouldn't be specifying `in-dyno` at all for `review`